# Can .dbc file parser for java

Tags: python, java, can-bus

Does java offer any library for parsing .dbc files and endcoding / decoding can messages?

I want to be able to parse a `.dbc` file, decode can messages and do some further processing with the obtained information but as I noticed java doesn't really offer much help in this direction.

Does someone know a way of achieving this in java or is it better to stick to python?

Comment: The Java JDK for sure does not read/write `.dbc` files. Java - just like Python btw - are general purpose programming languages. Some third party addon library might exist, but I have no clue what `.dbc` stands for. Find the right keywords and search for them.